# The --config-file option does not work in sysbench 1.1.0

Tags: testing, automated-tests, sysbench

I have encountered an issue with sysbench 1.1.0 where the configuration parameters specified in the configuration file using the `--config-file` option are not taking effect. I have specified the following configuration files:

```
db-driver=mysql
mysql-user=test
mysql-password=test123456
mysql-db=testdb
table-size=1000000
tables=10
```

or

```
memory-block-size=1M
memory-total-size=90G
```

I am running sysbench using the following commands:

```
sysbench --config-file=testconfig.cfg /usr/local/share/sysbench/oltp_read_write.lua prepare
```

or

```
sysbench --config-file=config.cfg memory run
```

I have confirmed that the path to the configuration file is correct. However, none of these configuration parameters seem to be taking effect when I run sysbench using the `--config-file` option. On the other hand, if I specify the same parameters directly on the command line, they work as expected.

I suspect that these configuration parameters may not be set through config-file in the source code, which could be the reason why they are not taking effect. Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?